# Python3.9 Django Docker Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, alpine-linux, python-3.9

I'm trying to update my docker image switching from **python:3.8.2-alpine3.10** to **python:3.9.0-alpine3.12**, but I'm getting an issue when running django commands *SSL_check_private_key: symbol not found*.

I get the following error when running checks:

bash -c "touch /var/donor_reporting_portal/.touch && django-admin check --deploy "
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/environ/environ.py:628: UserWarning: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/donor_reporting_portal/config/.env doesn't exist - if you're not configuring your environment separately, create one.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 8, in 
sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 377, in execute
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 24, in setup
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 790, in exec_module
File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/apps.py", line 1, in 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 51, in 
ImportError: Error relocating /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: SSL_check_private_key: symbol not found
make[2]: *** [.run] Error 1
make[1]: *** [test] Error 2
make: *** [build] Error 2

I don't get any issue when running this on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres functionality relies on a binary that is not portable and generally must be compiled on the target system and version of Python. Psycopg2 is built and released for every version of Python, but the 3.9 version of psycopg2 has not yet been released.

So, as of today, [Psycopg2 on Python 3.9 is not yet supported](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1160#issuecomment-706099169).

Comment: Now psycopg2 has been updated and made compatible:
https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/#files
but I still get the same issue

Comment: the ticket you're linking is a windows ticket